How to remove between only the first two matching patterns in a string?
Say I have x
x <- 'This is the <span I want to remove this> text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string.'

and I want x <- 'This is the text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string.'
How would I do that?
So far I did the following, but it got rid of text I wanted to keep:
sub("<span.*>", "", x)
#> [1] "This is the , in the string."

Thanks

* is greedy (will take as much as possible) *? is not. sub("<span.*?>", "", x) should work.

And more generally, sub('<.*?>', '', x) as the 'what' between a pair of chevrons may differ in say an xml, but won't work as desired without the thrifty ?, properly placed. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Try sub("<[^>]*>","",x).

Possible duplicated: Removing html tags from a string in R
Are you trying to parse html with regex?
If so, that's not the best approach: RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags
Try this:
library(rvest)

x <- 'This is the <span I want to remove this> text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string.'

html_text(read_html(x))

Output x:
[1] "This is the  text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string."

From a txt file:
x <- read_file("temp.txt") # Content bellow
cat(rvest::html_text(read_html(x)))

Output temp.txt:
Say I have x
x <- 'This is the <span I want to remove this> text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string.'

and I want x <- 'This is the text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, >, in the string.'
How would I do that?
So far I did the following, but it got rid of text I wanted to keep:
sub("<span.*>", "", x)
#> [1] "This is the , in the string."

Thanks

temp.txt content:
<div class="postcell post-layout--right">
    
<div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
                
<p>Say I have x</p>
<pre class="lang-r s-code-block"><code class="hljs language-r">x <span class="hljs-operator">&lt;-</span> <span class="hljs-string">'This is the &lt;span I want to remove this&gt; text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, &gt;, in the string.'</span>
</code></pre>
<p>and I want <code>x &lt;- 'This is the text I would like. But we must check I can have another chevron, &gt;, in the string.'</code></p>
<p>How would I do that?</p>
<p>So far I did the following, but it got rid of text I wanted to keep:</p>
<pre class="lang-r s-code-block"><code class="hljs language-r">sub<span class="hljs-punctuation">(</span><span class="hljs-string">"&lt;span.*&gt;"</span><span class="hljs-punctuation">,</span> <span class="hljs-string">""</span><span class="hljs-punctuation">,</span> x<span class="hljs-punctuation">)</span>
<span class="hljs-comment">#&gt; [1] "This is the , in the string."</span>
</code></pre>
<p>Thanks</p>
</div>

